# Java: Netbeans - no suitable driver found for jdbc mysql (after building and cleaning the project)

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, jar

In Netbeans I've selected the 'build and clean' option on my project, however if I move the .jar file from the /dist folder, I get this error: 
"Error: not suitable driver found for 'my database url here'"

Now I know that the database connection works because when I run the project in netbeans I'm able to retrieve and input data into the database, if I leave the .jar file in the /dist folder it works with no problems. Is there anyway I can include drivers when building the project? 
Feel free to tell me if this makes no sense and I'll try my best to elaborate.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

The problem here is your netbeans doesn't include required drived in build instead it is referring it from lib dir in dist

to kill this

goto netbeans project  > build.xml

before `</project>` add this

```
 <target name="-pre-jar">
    <unjar src="${file.reference.quartz-1.5.2.jar}" dest="${build.classes.dir}"/>
</target>
```

**Note:** quartz-1.5.2.jar will be referred by your project file.reference.quartz-1.5.2.jar
You can get such pointers from your `project.properties` file try to find jdbc jar's pointer and all required and add then this way it will work.

clean and build and run it from anywhere. it will include external libraries into build

Comment: I'm saying that if it were a problem with the JAR it would have been a ClassNotFoundException.  If you get the "no suitable driver" error it means the driver .class was found, but the URL syntax was incorrect.  Your solution addresses the wrong problem if I'm correct.

Comment: @user554031 Please follow this and let us know who is right :)

Comment: Hi, I've found the file build.xml, however I can't find <project> I've found <project name = TEXT HERE> I'm assuming you mean before this? If I do that, I get this error: Unexpected element "{}target" {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}target in the compiler

Comment: no , you just need to add `<target name="-pre-jar">    <unjar src="${file.reference.quartz-1.5.2.jar}" dest="${build.classes.dir}"/></target>` at the end of build.xml before `</project>` and please re-read the my answer

Comment: @duffymo I apologizes if it was bit rude, I would have upvoted you immediately upon your action but you deleted your post

Comment: No, not at all.  I deleted my post because it appears to have been incorrect.  You weren't being rude - we had a technical disagreement.  I have no problem with that at all.